# GDB stepping into source files

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

Hi I would like to ask a question about the internals of gdb. I have a function as below which just emulates a simple game of craps storing 2 rolls of the die in an array.

```
int roll_dice(void) {
   int r[R], i, sum = 0;    
   for (i = 0; i <= R-1; i++) {  
       r[i] = rand() % 7;}
   for (i = 0; i <= R-1; i++) {
       sum += r[i];}
   return sum;
   }
```

I would step through the program with gdb until I'd get an error:

```
27   rand.c: No such file or directory.
```

I now understand that gdb was "stepping" into a source file which it cannot find in its source path. I am able to get past the issue using "next" instead, but I would like to know if the rand.c is not in the source path how is gdb still able to call rand()?

Comment: `gdb` works with compiled code. Being able to find and display corresponding source is an optional extra.

Comment: This is a major difference between _compiled_ languages and _interpreted_ languages. After compiling, the source code is not necessary any more. -- Compare this to your own experiences with your programs: After compiling and linking, you can copy and run the executable on another system. The source code is not necessary to do that. If you try to debug on source level on this other system, GDB will moan as well for your modules.

Comment: The compiler adds debug information into the binary. That tells the debugger that some certain memory address has an identifier `roll_dice` or `rand` attached to it and the code stored at that address was created by compiling `rand.c`. That is enough to show names during debugging. But the source code itself is not added to the binary. You can step through such functions in assembler view but without the source you cannot inspect the C code.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, still a bit hazy on what compiled code actually is if not just the process from a high to low level instruction. GDB is then stepping through your program albeit has generated other debugging information for you aswell i.e the assembler view? In my case I guess I'm only concerned with my program, but can see easily how a larger project may require the source files to actually be on hand. Thanks again.